# Displaying limited items in combobox

Tags: c#, .net

In my project, I have a combobox and has 60 values in it. When I start running the application, I open the combobox to choose a value, it covers all my form application because it has lots of values in it. It does not look good visually. When I open the combobox to select a value, I want to display only 5 of them and user can select the other 55 item by scrolling down. How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Which UI technology do you use? Winforms? WPF? Webforms? Please also tag your question with this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `MaxDropDownItems` property of `combobox` to 5 and `IntegralHeight = true`

When IntegralHeight property is set to true, the control automatically resizes to ensure that an item is not partially displayed. If you want to maintain the original size of the ComboBox based on the space requirements of your form, set this property to false. If the ComboBox does not contain any items, this property has no effect.

**EDIT:** another possibility is to set the dropdownheight directly

```
comboBox1.DropDownHeight = comboBox1.Font.Height * 5;
```

Comment: @user1913674 did you set it to false before populating the combobox items?

Comment: @user1913674 you are welcome :) btw. I added another way to my answer